# Unable to find datatemplate by resourcekey

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress SchedulerControl and I'm also customizing the appointment templates. For one of the SchedulerControl's view properties I need to assign a template from my `window.resources` but I have

```
x:Key="{dxscht:SchedulerViewThemeKey ResourceKey=HorizontalAppointmentSameDayContentTemplate}"
```

and I want to refer to this template in my grid but I don't know what to use as the key.
When I iterate in the codebehind file through `Resources.Keys` I get a key called "SchedulerViewThemeKeyExtension_HorizontalAppointmentLongerThanADayContentTemplate" but TryFindResource returns always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out my self:

```
NeededTemplate="{StaticResource {dxscht:SchedulerViewThemeKey ResourceKey=HorizontalAppointmentSameDayContentTemplate}}"
```

solves the problem

Comment: You are allowed mark your answer to your own question, and it's even encouraged so that anyone searching for the same problem in the future can find the answer.  [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)